# QLabel limiting text length on second calling setText() to the length of the first value

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel

When setting a label in the init of a QWidget the text is shown properly, however on changing the text with the press of a button the text is not shown fully.
It is limited at the char length of the old string. How can this be solved?

Thanks in advance!

```py
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 500, 420)

        Button("Change it!", self).set_tool_tip("Change the label text").resize().move(0, 40).on_click(
            self.change_label)

        self.Label = QLabel(self)
        self.Label.setText("I'm going to change and get bigger!")
        self.Label.move(0, 65)

    def change_label(self):
        self.Label.setText("I'm bigger then I was before, unfortunately I'm not fully shown. Can you help me? :)")
```

Comment: use any layout manager and it will resize widgets automatically. Now you have to resize it on your own using `self.Label.resize(width, height)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change size manually using `self.Label.resize(width, height)` in `change_label`. But you don't know what value use as `width`

Better use any layout manager and it will resize widget automatically.

Example with layout manager Vertical Boxes - `QVBoxLayout`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.button = QPushButton("Change it!", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.change_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("I'm going to change and get bigger!")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

    def change_label(self):
        self.label.setText("I'm bigger then I was before, unfortunately I'm not fully shown. Can you help me? :)")


app = QApplication([])
main = MainWindow()
main.show()
app.exec()
```